# OrientDB v3.2.21 - No more resources available in pool (max = 50)

Tags: orientdb, tinkerpop, orientdb3.0

I'm upgrading from OrientDB v2 with Tinkerpop 2.0 to OrientDB v3.2.21 with the Tinkerpop 3.0. In OrientDB v2, I've always use the OrientGraphFactory with `setupPool(1, 50)`. However, in OrientDB v3, if I use OrientGraphFactory with `setupPool(50)`, I keep getting the error "No more resources available in pool (max=50)" which I never get the error in OrientDB v2. Is it because OrientDB v2 is able to wait until the pool resource is freed up while OrientDB v3 just throw the error?

I know I can fixed this by increasing the maximum pool size, but I would like to have a more elegant way to fix the issue. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found that there is a timeout config value in OGlobalConfiguration in Orient V3 - `db.pool.acquireTimeout` which default to 60000ms. In my case, I need to increase the timeout value so that it's able to wait until the pool is freed up.